# Can I migrate a Teams app from one tenant to another?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have a Teams bot application setup with one tenant. This application has live users and we are performing actions based on conversation-ids, etc on our servers. Is there any way to migrate this application to another tenant without disrupting end user flows? The end users do not belong to my organization. I need to migrate it in such a way that end users do not see any change

Comment: Before you can migrate your bot, you need to prepare the new tenant. This includes setting up the necessary permissions and configurations in the new tenant. You can refer:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/prepare-your-o365-tenant. Once the new tenant is prepared, you can deploy your bot to the new tenant. Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deploy-and-publish/apps-upload
If your bot uses any tenant-specific settings or configurations, you will need to update those to reflect the new tenant.